# I need hover effect on hovering in wordpress css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need hover effect  in wordpress css check here

https://preview.themeforest.net/item/jobster-job-board-html-template/full_screen_preview/34961930?_ga=2.136566064.165143227.1680854976-1104485318.1680608393&_gac=1.255701498.1680858744.Cj0KCQjw_r6hBhDdARIsAMIDhV9I_llKei3TJbQTCXfjG_GJmzjoE538Nk84ngyrdHAGgYzABAYxQ90aAm3wEALw_wcB

check job card image....I want highlight border of the card on hover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGAMC.png)

below is the class

.pxp-jobs-card-2.pxp-has-border {
}

If you have any plugin please letme know as i dont know css in wordpress

Thanks in advance

I tried a hover but it didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a plugin, you just need to customise the CSS. Select **Customise** in the admin bar at the top, then **Additional CSS**. Then you'll need to enter something like this:

```
.pxp-jobs-card-2.pxp-has-border:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

PS. There is another Stack Exchange site specifically for [WordPress questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).